# Aligning two HTML objects side by side

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I have a color box and some text. I'm trying to align the box exactly left of the text. I'm having issues trying to align it correctly.

I've tried looking at other posts on stack overflow and tried using the float property but couldn't align them correctly because the text goes too far to the right when using the float property. Here is the jsfiddle link if someone wants to run the code : https://jsfiddle.net/1qgep5tn/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<style>

  .box {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
   }

  .boxColor {
      background: #1c5a7d;
  }

    #right{
      float: right;
    }

    #left{
      float: left;
    } 

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="box boxColor" ></div>       
   Header:
     <br>
          <input type="text" name="firstname"  value="">
     <br>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting the box to be aligned left of the text but it is appearing above the text. Here is an image of what it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: You may refer the following web page:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSFiddle looks different than how you have it unless its edited. change the Heading `<div>` to a `<p>` and make sure its next to the box like this:

```
<div class="google_map">
    <div class="box blueish"></div>
    <p class="paragraph">Header:</p>
  </div>
```

and use `display: inline-block` in both the classes `paragraph` and `box`.

Answer (score 1):

With that HTML you are going to have a lot of trouble aligning the items as you want. This is because there is no main container wrapping all of the text content. I would first suggest wrapping your text content in another container, and using a label for the input, such as:

```
<div class="box boxColor"></div>
<div class="box boxText">
    <label for="firstname">
        <span>Header</span>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"
                value="">
    </label>
 </div>
```

With that structure, you can better apply styling:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
label > span {
    display: block
}
label > span::after {
    content: ":";
}
.box {
    /* whatever shared styles you might want... */
}
.boxColor {
    background-color: #1c5a7d;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
.boxText {
    flex-grow: 1
}
```